# How can I edit message by id?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I change a message by its ID? I have the following code:

```js
    client.on('message', message => {
        if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'edit')) {
            let msg1 = ['message'];
            const desc = msg1.content.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ');
            const desc2 = msg1.content.split(' ').slice(3).join(' ');
            const desc3 = msg1.content.split(' ').slice(4).join(' ');
            let server = client.guilds.cache.get(desc);
            if (!server) console.log('Не могу получить сервер')
            let channel = server.channels.cache.get(desc2);
            if (!channel) console.log('Не могу получить канал')
            let message = channel.messages.fetch(desc3).then(msg => {
                msg.edit('hello')
            })
        }
    })
```

And I can't make it so that the user can choose which message to change.

Comment: why is `msg1` simply `['message']`?

Comment: Also make sure that the message you want to edit is sent by your **own** bot. Messages sent by others **cannot be edited.**